# How to find a time stamp is morning, afternoon or evening in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to find out whether a timestamp in a table is morning, afternoon or evening. Currently, I have the following code:

```
case 
   when datepart(hour, o.timestamp) between 5 and 12 
      then 'Morning' 
   when datepart(hour, o.timestamp) between 13 and 17 
      then 'Afternoon' 
   when datepart(hour, o.timestamp) > 17 
      then 'Evening' 
end
```

The problem with the above code is that 2018-08-03 17:30:00.000 comes out as afternoon instead of the evening. That's because the hour in 2018-08-03 17:30:00.000 is 17 so it's evaluated as the afternoon. Instead, I want to include the minute part also which will then become evening.

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to change `between 13 and 17` to `between 13 and 16`, so you'd include everything from 13:00:00 to 16:59:59,99999.

Answer (score 3):

How about time comparisons?

```
(case when convert(time, o.timestamp) >= '05:00:00' and
           convert(time, o.timestamp) < '12:00:00'
      then 'morning'
      when convert(time, o.timestamp) >= '12:00:00' and
           convert(time, o.timestamp) < '17:00:00'
      then 'afternoon'
      else 'evening'
 end)
```

Note that your logic doesn't account for hours between midnight and 5 a.m.

You can do something similar with the hour itself, but I think times will be less confusing for you to work with.  Also, I don't know if the boundary for morning is really noon or 1:00 p.m.  Your query suggests that the boundary is 1:00 p.m.  Common sense suggests noon.  That is easily adjusted in the `case` expression.

Comment: Between midnight and 5 am will also be considered an evening.

Comment: @Massey . . . I just changed the last clause to `else`.